# Multiplying a vector by different values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a array, where i would like to multiply the elements inside the array by themselves (product) and i have the following vector to be multiplied by the input vector: test_vector = `array([0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)`.

I am looking for an easy way to automate this task

Comment: Why is the last element of `new_vector` `0.31`? Shouldn't it be `0.69` since `new_input` is `1`?

Comment: Are these numpy arrays?

Comment: They are numpy arrays, yes, i've added more example for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy solution:

```py
import numpy as np

arr_1 = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
arr_2 = np.array([0.42, 0.53, 0.62, 0.60, 0.69])

res = np.prod(np.where(arr_1, arr_2, 1 - arr_2))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
0.033779088
```

There might be a more efficient way.

Comment: Yep.  The best answer if using Numpy.  When I gave my answer, he hadn't yet specified Numpy, and I wasn't going to add that level of difficulty if not needed

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're calling that first array.  I'm calling it `signs`.

```
result = 1
for sign, value in zip(signs, test_vector):
    result *= (value if sign == 0 else 1 - value)
```

If these vectors are long rather than short examples as given here, you might want to switch to using numpy.